# Modern page's banner images is raising this error on IE "Object doesn't support property or method 'trunc'"

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

we have a modern page which have a banner image, this is working on chrome, firefox but on IE-11 users are reporting this error:-

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'trunc'
```

[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you using custom SPFx web part or any SharePoint OOTB web part?

Comment: @GaneshSanap no i am only using built-in web parts

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Internet Explorer 11 with all the usual default settings e.g. document mode is set to 11 etc and encountering the error when using an out-of-the-box feature then you may need to raise a support ticket with Microsoft. You can do this from the Microsoft 365 admin center.

If the error is caused by a custom solution which you have developed, you may need to look at using polyfills in your solution that will resolve problems that occur when specific features are not supported in Internet Explorer.